# Raspbeery (bullseye) && libcamera

Tags: bullseye

After running **libcamera-hello** I've always this error (I've **Raspbian GNU/Linux 11** (bullseye))

Made X/EGL preview window

```
[0:01:17.403440281] [1320]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

What can I edit on **config.txt** !! Is there any modification on raspi-config???

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you have already checked the issue in the repository, I attach it just in case, anyway I will make a summary:

- verify that your system detects the camera with the command `sudo vcgencmd get_camera`.
- in the `/boot/config.txt` file remove the `#` or add the following

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
dtoverlay=imx219
```

- Reboot your Raspberry

Good luck

Issue: https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/125

Comment: Just a suggestion, I see that you are new here, I recommend you to see the suggestions on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but above all try to give more details of the problem, such as logs, system information, and to answer you quickly and correctly, try to add the tags that correspond, in this case, raspberry, debian, bullseye, camera, any that you consider prudent, but do not exaggerate xd, good luck :D

Comment: I really appreciate your advice ; sure I will the next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I manage to resolve this problem finally:
so if you've debian bullseye raspberry pi os First install the camera software and drivers if they don't exist then in config.txt: check that you uncomment `camera_auto_detect=1` and add `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`

- In interface options if you run `sudo raspi-config`: do not enable the lagacy camera but navigate to Advanced Options and enable Glamor graphic acceleration then reboot
- If you run `sudo vcgencmd get_camera` it's unneeded to detect you camera with this command it's not neccesary with bullseye version